# Asp.Net Identity: Login with facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-identity

I just created an ASP.Net MVC project inside my solution, following [`these instructions`](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

After successfully being able to login and create users with a custom `IUserStore`, I followed [`these instructions`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx) to allow login with social networks like facebook:

Unfortunately, after doing this, I realized that the login does not work, since this code simply hangs:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, 
                                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { 
                           IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

I tried stepping into or looking for documentation about it, but I'm A bit lost...

```
identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, 
                     DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm using .net Framework 4.5, MVC v5 and Visual Studio 2013

Comment: what .net version are you using?

Comment: @ps2goat, I guess 4.5 since `Async/Await` are used.

Comment: @christiandev, that's why I was verifying, to make sure those could be used.

Comment: @ps2goat, it wouldn't `hang`, it would not even compile.

Comment: @christiandev, it doesn't matter.  clarification is a good thing.  If we move on to asp.net 5, someone may try these answers without knowing if it relates to their framework version

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

It is simple and works pretty good for me.

If you want to claim additional info from Facebook provider, then simply add to your *OwinStartup.cs* something like that:

```
FacebookAuthenticationOptions facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "PutYourFacebookAppIdHere",
    AppSecret = "PutYourFacebookAppSecretHere"
};
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```